# Export figure as PDF with surrounding white space cropped out

Tags: windows-7, pdf, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

I exported a chart from a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet by selecting the chart, the File > Export > Create PDF/XPS document, with the following options:

[image]

The result is nice except that:

[image]

How can I export the figure so that the surrounding blank space is crop out? I'm OK if the solution requires to change the chart itself.

My original chart is Excel looks like this:

[image]

This is the output that I would like to get:

[image]

(I cropped the PDF manually using [BRISS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/)):

[image]

I use Microsoft Excel 2013 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely seeing either or both of:

1. Page layout > Page setup > Margin > Custom Margins  in Excel
2. The empty cells surrounding your graph: I suggest you "Define a print area".

[image]

[image]

Comment: *Page layout > Page setup > Margins in Excel* did the trick, I didn't think it would apply for select areas. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: =) That edit is likely a bit slanted against Excel, but still shows it well.

Comment: Hmm actually *Page layout > Page setup > Margins in Excel* does the trick when both the figure's height and width is larger than the page's height and width. Otherwise there is still some whitespace around, even when setting margins to 0 :-/ Defining a print area didn't help either.

Comment: I can imagine this to depend a bit on which version you're using.